# Wrong hyphenation with \usepackage[croatian]{babel}

Tags: babel, hyphenation

The words 'izoliran' and 'kostur' in the MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[croatian]{babel}

\begin{document}
    mmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm izoliran

    mmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm kostur
\end{document}
```

are not hyphenated correctly: they appear as iz-oliran and kos-tur on my end. Hyphenation for other languages seems to work fine, and mostly agrees with what the Croatian one should be (i-zo-li-ran and ko-stur).
For what it's worth, I'm using a recently updated TexLive installation, and what seems to be the latest version of Babel (the documentation is version 3.9l).
Is this a real problem with the hyphenation patterns for this particular language, or is something else going on?

As for the solution, almost anything would be better than the English patterns that seem to be used now. Is there a way to use [croatian]{babel} with the hyphenation patterns of another language? Serbian, for example, would be close to perfect.

Edit: what I said about English patterns being used is definitively wrong, so these syllabifications are what they are 'by design'.

Comment: `\hyphenation{i-zo-li-ran ko-stur}` but that's just for exceptions, this seems to be a larger problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the hyphenation is really wrong (I take your word for it), the first thing to do is to make aware of this the people who are responsible for the hyphenation patterns at the mailing list about [hyphenation in TeX](http://tug.org/mailman/listinfo/tex-hyphen). I find nothing about the problem in that list, though.

In the meantime, you can enable the patterns for Serbian with the help of `hyphsubst`:

```
\RequirePackage[croatian=serbian]{hyphsubst}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[croatian]{babel}

\usepackage{testhyphens}

\begin{document}

\begin{checkhyphens}
izoliran kostur
\end{checkhyphens}

\end{document}
```

The main part is the initial `\RequirePackage`, while `testhyphens` is used just for showing all the hyphenation places in the given words.

[image]

Looking in the hyphenation pattern files, the `kos-tur` break seems a deliberate choice for Croatian, for the pattern is `s1t`, while in the file for Serbian there is `s2t`. According to the Liang algorithm, odd numbers mark feasible hyphenation places, while even numbers mark unfeasible points.

However, there's something strange happening, because the pattern `z<digit>o` never appears in `hyph-hr.tex`; instead I find `a1zo`, `e1zo`, `i1zo`, `o1zo` and `u1zo` that would imply no break can be inserted between `z` and `o`.

***But*** at the end of the file there is `.iz1`, which explains the bad hyphenation.

The author of the patterns is Igor Marinović, whose email address is listed in `hyph-hr.tex`.

Comment: Perhaps note that `i-zo-li-ran` also requires a change to the minimum hyphenation numbers?

Comment: @JosephWright Neither Croatian nor Serbian babel sets the hyphen minima, so they're the default 2 and 3. Setting `\lefthyphenmin=1` doesn't seem a good idea anyway.

Comment: I am aware of lefthyphenmin restriction, it is not a problem, I was thinking of the syllabification when I wrote i-zo-li-ran.

As for the correctness, there is as many orthography manuals for Croatian as there are people who deem themselves competent enough to write one, so I can't speak for all of them, but iz-o-li-ran and kos-tur make no sense either phonologically or morphologically.

And I noticed the same thing you did when I looked at the hyph-hr.tex, but I assumed I'm either misunderstanding it or that there's something wrong on my end.
I'll try contacting the author when I get the time

Comment: @user54748 The Croatian patterns were last updated in 1996: I'd be tempted to raise on the hyphenation list!

Comment: (meanwhile this solution works perfectly - thanks!)

Comment: @user54748 I found the culprit: a surely wrong pattern `.iz1` that should evidently be `.iz2`, maybe supplemented by some `.iz3<letters>` for allowing hyphenation in cases like `izv...` (I guess there are words starting with `izv`, but I may be wrong). The patterns for Serbian seem much more detailed.

Comment: Thanks for finding it. And I'm not sure it's a mistake, the intention was probably to allow hyphenations such as `iz-obličen', coincidental with the morpheme boundary (iz-/is- is a common prefix - cf. the next line).
But allowing a single (arguably) correct hyphenation and a lot of wrong ones (iz-omorfizam, iz-oliran, etc.) is probably not the best tradeoff.